# How can I get the url from file uploaded in Media Library

Tags: links

In my template i'm using a link for downloading a file (probably a PDF or a JPEG) that I will upload from Media Library.
How can I get the url path for this specific file?
What template tag I have to use?

Thanks

Comment: How is the file connected to the page/post in the template? How do you tell it apart from all the other files

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. I need to have this link in the home (front-page.php). Is that what you meen?

Comment: This one will get you the media-url from the unique-id of the media-item https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/

Comment: I mean if you want to show a file you've uploaded in a place, you need to know its ID and have that stored somewhere, but if all you've done is go to the media section and uploaded it, how do we know which file you meant to display? Have you considered just having a page as your front page, and using a file block? Or inserting an attachment into the page as a link?

Comment: Maybe I am a bit confused about how to get it..
Let me give you more context...I just want to have a link in my home page, so when users click on it they will download my CV...
I thought i needed to upload it by Media Library and then get the URL through some template tag and put it in my page..
This is not the right way to do it?

Comment: Maybe I should put it inside the theme's folder and link to it using get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
For example: href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/cv.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way is to upload the file in a separate folder from media library and then call it by using get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

For example: dist/img/cv.pdf">

Answer (score 0):

All uploads to Media Library have their link saved.  Click on the image, find the Details Section. Click on More Details.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should create custom field and place media url in that, call custom fields in home page by code. Reference URL: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/